# How to run django app in heroku with DEBUG=False

Tags: django, heroku

I know this may be asked before, but I have tried a lot to get it right but it just won't.
I have tried setting DEBUG=False and then setting ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] as many posts here o SO and on medium suggested.
please help me get this to work or link to a recent answer that got it right.
I have django_herokuu installed already.
Below is my settings.py file. When I run it like that I get a 500 error

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Comment: I think, you should run your server locally with debug False, that might show actually why its failing. Because, allowed hosts * should allow any host to be used.

Comment: if the error is related to hostname issue, the error should be `400` instead of `500`, I think your code may get other errors, so just do as `ruddra` suggestion...

Comment: Did that guys. I got a 500 error. I have tried setting ALLOWED_HOSTS =['localhost'] but that too doesn't work.

Comment: Try to change `DEBUG` to `True` and see if you still get a 500. If not, then find all conditional statements in your code that use `DEBUG` and see if they all branch correctly